# Matching Binary Vectors

Tags: pattern-matching, logical-operators, binary-data

Assume I have two binary vectors A and B and I want to see and compute how similar they are. For instance A = 01011001 and B = 10010101. Now the matching would be something like:

A = 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1

B = 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1

---

C = 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 = 4/8 or 50%

Now, this is something that can be very easily implemented with XNOR gates. But what if I want to do the same bitwise matching but in a different way. For instance,

A (MSBs) = 0 1 0 1

B (MSBs) = 1 0 0 1

A (LSBs) = 1 0 0 1

B (LSBs) = 0 1 0 1

---

C = -----------------

Is there a way to compute the similarity vector C (and its %), by doing some arithmetic/logical operation on the 4 columns?

Thanks.

Comment: what is MSB and LSB?

Comment: MSB is the most significant and LSB is the least significant bits. So A(MSB) means the first 4 bits of A, starting from the most significant left bit position and so on.

Comment: You haven't gotten much help. Perhaps I can point you to [The Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com), which may be a more relevant place to put it, to understand the mathematics behind your prospective method.